# Image grayed out when disabled

Tags: css, asp.net

Is this possible not to grayed out control when it is disabled?

I need to use custom calendar control which has third party rjs calnedar control with image and textbox but when i disabled them they grayed out which i think it suppose to do.

Is there any way not to grayed out calendar image when disabled?

[image]

**ADDED**

It looks like that third party calendar is showing different calendar image denpends on disable property of this control.

Is there any way to change the image which is already rendered? 
There is one custom control which has text box and third party calendar.

Comment: Why not modify the CSS with an override rule for the custom calendar?

Comment: okay, it is showing disabled image if its disable, how can i overide image and show different one?<img border="0" align="absmiddle" src="/PopCalendar/DisabledCalendar.gif"></img>

Comment: Can you add a "class='calendar'" and then use CSS to pick up the `.calendar disabled { background-image : url(....) !important; }` ?

Answer (score 0):

Just go to that source: /PopCalendar, copy calender image ex: Calendar.gif  and replace it with DisabledCalendar.gif. problem solved..

Comment: can't do it as it is set in custom calendar dll file, is there any way to change image which is rendering on page

Comment: Dude there will be an directory where these images will be right? so copy that calender icon and replace it with the disabled one what is the problem? just name the copied one as  DisabledCalendar.gif..

Comment: i have updated my question. This calendar control has been used on number of places within the application so i can't touch that image plus its been set within dll file.